# Does MongoDb C# Samus have Indexing feature?

Tags: indexing, mongodb

I was trying out MongoDb c# driver by Samus. Is there any way to index the documents using this driver? Does it provide that feature? If it does please let me know how to. I could not find proper documentation for this.

Regards,
Lalith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **MongoDB.CollectionMetadata** to create indexed in mongo db

Below the sample

```
            CollectionMetadata cmd = DB["indextests"].MetaData;
            cmd.CreateIndex("lastnames", new Document().Add("lname", IndexOrder.Ascending), false);
            Dictionary<string, Document> indexes = cmd.Indexes;
```

Comment: Hi Ramesh, Thank you for the code. Where can I find documentation for this driver? - Lalith

Comment: @lalith, I am not sure about the documentation. But the driver project also got the tests included.